# How to pass data between two classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to pass user input gathered using a text field in a ViewController class to a UIView class so as to plot user inputted points using the drawRect method. I have experimented with creating a method that passes the input from the textField to a method called `findXValue`, but am not sure how to share that data between `ViewController` and `graphView`. Perhaps an interface covering both classes would work, but as I am unexperienced in using Xcode I have no idea of how I might do that.
Here is my code:

UIView Interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface graphView : UIView

@end
```

graphView implementation:

```
#import "graphView.h"

@implementation graphView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 30,30);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 30.0f, 260.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    CGContextRef d = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColor(d, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(d);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(d, 30,260);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(d, 400.0f, 260.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(d);
}

@end
```

ViewController interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *xTextField;

- (NSString *)findXValue:(NSString*)xValue;

@end

NSString *xValue;
```

ViewController implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.xTextField.text);

    xValue = self.xTextField.text;
    [self findXValue:xValue];

    [self.xTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSString *)findXValue:(NSString*)xValue{
    NSLog(@"%@",xValue);
    return xValue;
}


@end
```

Thanks.

AMEND AFTER ANSWER FROM ASA:
Seemed to compile at first, but broke on runtime. Here is the code:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "graphView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *xTextField;
- (NSString *)findXValue:(NSString*)xValue;

@property (nonatomic, strong) graphView* graphView1; 

@end

NSString *xValue;
NSString *finalXValue;
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.xTextField.text);

    xValue = self.xTextField.text;
    [self findXValue:xValue];

    [self.xTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSString *)findXValue:(NSString*)xValue{
    NSLog(@"%@",xValue);
    self.graphView1 = [[graphView alloc] init];
    self.graphView1.xNum = xValue;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.graphView1.xNum);
    [self.graphView1 findX:xValue];
    /*
    graphView *graphViewPlz = [[graphView alloc] init];
    graphView.xNum.viewDidLoad;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphViewPlz animated:YES];
     */
    finalXValue = xValue;
    return xValue;
}


@end
```

graphView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface graphView : UIView
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *isSomethingEnabled;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *xNum;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* viewController;
- (void) findX:(NSString*)xValue;
@end

NSString *xValue;
```

graphView.m:

```
#import "graphView.h"

@implementation graphView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.xNum);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 30,30);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 30.0f, 260.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    CGContextRef d = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColor(d, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(d);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(d, 30,260);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(d, 400.0f, 260.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(d);
}

- (void) findX:(NSString*)xValue{
    NSLog(@"%@",xValue);
}

@end
```

THANKS!

Comment: Adding to Asa Dickens answer, to update your view, when you have set your coordinates you could call setNeedsDisplay

Comment: "Broke on runtime" is not an adequate description of an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a separate class GraphView.h (which you did) and make that a property of the viewcontroller aka with in the viewcontroller.h file put this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GraphView* graphView;
```

and remember to put this at the top

```
#import "GraphView.h"
```

from there you could have properties for the graphView. You could allocate the graphview when ever you need it

```
self.graphView = [[GraphView alloc] init];
```

and then call methods on that object.
if you do not know when to do that, just put it with in the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {}
```

method. Now when you want to pass data you can call methods like

```
[self.graphView configureWithXPoints:xpoints];
```

or set properties

```
self.graphView.data = newData;
```

and that would be the gist of passing information around... between a view and a view controller. Remember the `drawRect` method is not called until it's time to draw so when you want it to update on the screen, you have to either manually call that or re-add that view to the viewController.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your answer seemed to compile at first, but then when I attempted to run it I received the error message **unknown type graphView** which is weird because I have a class graphView that is imported. I'll amend the question.

Comment: hmm, try restarting xCode, if that does not work, check the case sensitivity, those are my first instincts when i get those errors... simply because recently xCode has told me it couldn't find stuff... when i knew it was there....